# Can OpenStack be configured to start certain instances when the hypervisor reboots?

Tags: openstack, kvm, openstack-nova

Say we have a power outage, and a hypervisor gets reset. Openstack will start up the nova services, etc.

But, it will not start back up any VMs which were running when the hypervisor went down. Can it be configured to do this?

Perhaps one workaround would be a to make a startup script on the hypervisor, or a crontask somewhere, which starts specified VMs assigned to that hypervisor if they are not running, but that's less than ideal..

- Currently running Havana with KVM, but will be upgrading to Icehouse soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this section in /etc/nova/nova.conf:

```
# Whether to start guests that were running before the host
# rebooted (boolean value)
#resume_guests_state_on_host_boot=false
```

If you uncomment that last line, and change it to =true, then restart nova services everywhere, that *should* do what you want.